# Trying to create a table in AWS Athena using a query

Tags: amazon-athena

I have tried and failed many times t create a table in Athena via the create table from s3 bucket data

I have two other tables that work built by a previous colleague

Every time I try using the "Create table from s3 data I get a Json error.
Every time I use a query i get the following error

> mismatched input 'external'. expecting: 'or', 'schema', 'table', 'view' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: feb29e62-e93a-47cf-bccc-5c2f8a4916a1; proxy: null)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable`(
  `myfield1` string, 
  `myfield2` string, 
  `myfield3` string, 
  `myfield4` string,)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://mybucket/myfolder/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='true',)
```

Comment: Did you try using Glue Crawler to map your data? Do you have an example of your data? Is it really encrypted?

Comment: It is encrypted as it has a little padlock next to it

Comment: HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value for field 0: org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONArray

Comment: This error usually means a syntax error somewhere. You have an extra `,` next to `myfield4` column and another one next to `has_encrypted_data`. Yes, the error message is confusing.

Comment: DDL
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `mytable`(
  `myfield1` string, 
  `myfield1` string, 
  `lmyfield1` string, 
  `myfield1` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' 
  MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY 'undefined' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'collection.delim'=',') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://mys3'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='true', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1624983740')

Comment: Actual data:
{"myfield1":"myresult1","myfield2":"myresult2","myfield3":"myresult3","myfield4":"myresult4"}

Just not being delimited properly now

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma in tblproperties.That might be an issue.
TBLPROPERTIES (
'has_encrypted_data'='true',)
try removing that and see.

Answer (score 0):

One issue could be - you have put a comma after the last field name and type.

`myfield4` string,

Remove this and try once.